# Chrome crash after malware removal (browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(103) Failed to launch GPU process.) Windows10

Tags: google-chrome, logging, crash, gpu

After removing a malware withing chrome (which open ad tab and search with Yahoo) I got some issue. Chrome crash frequently. Sometime it came back without reason, other time after launching Canary. But now it isn't starting anymore, be it normal Chrome or Canary, and after having removed the program, all folder, restarted the computeur, delete registry key, deactivated extension, deleted user data and tried using without my account and synced data, I'm still having the error.

All page are black with a error icon. I can't acceed anything, not even the settings. I tried to get a log and saw this in the console : 
**[5228:9564:0725/190255.609:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(103)] Failed to launch GPU process.** for the two chrome.

To get rid of my malware I used malwarebyte, malwarebyte rootkit beta, adwcleaner, hitman pro, SuperAntiSpyware portable, JRT, Rkill and ccleaner, all in safe mode (I follow a post on the net). I got an issue then with windows service, but I solved it by putting service activation list by default. The malware was in chrome sync data so I had to remove it too. The malware isn't there anymore, but I don't know if it can be the cause of my current issue. I haven't had Canary installed at that time.

Here's the log file for normal Chrome :

> [4576:5528:0725/193214.003:VERBOSE1:policy_loader_win.cc(376)] Reading
>   policy from the registry is disabled.
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.025:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: Google 'Aviator' log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.025:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: Google 'Icarus' log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.025:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: Google 'Pilot' log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.025:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: Google 'Rocketeer' log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.025:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: Google 'Skydiver' log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.025:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: DigiCert Log Server
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.025:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: DigiCert Log Server 2
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.025:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: Symantec log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.025:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: Symantec 'Vega' log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.025:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: Symantec 'Sirius' log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.025:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: WoSign log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.025:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: Venafi Gen2 CT log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.025:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: CNNIC CT log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.025:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: StartCom log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.025:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: Comodo 'Sabre' CT log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.025:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: Comodo 'Mammoth' CT log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.025:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: Izenpe log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.025:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: Venafi log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.025:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: Certly.IO log
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.032:VERBOSE1:pref_proxy_config_tracker_impl.cc(154)]
>   0000027FB7FEF0F0: set chrome proxy config service to 0000027FB7F948C0
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.032:VERBOSE1:pref_proxy_config_tracker_impl.cc(281)]
>   0000027FB7FEF0F0: Done pushing proxy to UpdateProxyConfig
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.036:VERBOSE1:install_util.cc(178)] Existing
>   Google Chrome version found 60.0.3112.72
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.048:VERBOSE1:mutable_profile_oauth2_token_service_delegate.cc(160)] MutablePO2TS::MutablePO2TS
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.048:VERBOSE1:device_event_log_impl.cc(158)]
>   [19:32:14.048] Bluetooth: EVENT: bluetooth_api.cc:68 BluetoothAPI:
>   0000027FB7EB7D10
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.048:VERBOSE1:bluetooth_low_energy_event_router.cc(248)]
>   Initializing BluetoothLowEnergyEventRouter.
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.053:VERBOSE1:pref_proxy_config_tracker_impl.cc(154)]
>   0000027FB7E75E90: set chrome proxy config service to 0000027FB8C2AE40
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.053:VERBOSE1:pref_proxy_config_tracker_impl.cc(281)]
>   0000027FB7E75E90: Done pushing proxy to UpdateProxyConfig
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.053:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: Google 'Aviator' log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.053:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: Google 'Icarus' log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.053:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: Google 'Pilot' log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.053:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: Google 'Rocketeer' log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.053:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: Google 'Skydiver' log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.053:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: DigiCert Log Server
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.053:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: DigiCert Log Server 2
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.053:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: Symantec log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.053:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: Symantec 'Vega' log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.053:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: Symantec 'Sirius' log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.053:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: WoSign log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.053:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: Venafi Gen2 CT log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.053:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: CNNIC CT log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.053:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: StartCom log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.053:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: Comodo 'Sabre' CT log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.053:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: Comodo 'Mammoth' CT log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.053:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: Izenpe log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.053:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: Venafi log
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.053:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)]
>   Adding CT log: Certly.IO log
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.055:VERBOSE1:extension_service.cc(1617)]
>   AddComponentExtension Bookmark Manager
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.055:VERBOSE1:extension_service.cc(1617)]
>   AddComponentExtension Cloud Print
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.056:VERBOSE1:extension_service.cc(1617)]
>   AddComponentExtension Web Store
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.056:VERBOSE1:extension_service.cc(1617)]
>   AddComponentExtension Google Hangouts
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.057:VERBOSE1:extension_service.cc(1617)]
>   AddComponentExtension Feedback
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.057:VERBOSE1:extension_service.cc(1617)]
>   AddComponentExtension Google Network Speech
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.058:VERBOSE1:extension_service.cc(1617)]
>   AddComponentExtension CryptoTokenExtension
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.058:VERBOSE1:extension_service.cc(1617)]
>   AddComponentExtension Chrome PDF Viewer
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.059:VERBOSE1:account_reconcilor.cc(74)]
>   AccountReconcilor::AccountReconcilor
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.059:VERBOSE1:account_reconcilor.cc(85)]
>   AccountReconcilor::Initialize
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.063:VERBOSE1:ev_whitelist_component_installer.cc(150)]
>   Registering EV whitelist component.
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.063:VERBOSE1:file_type_policies_component_installer.cc(129)]
>   Registering File Type Policies component.
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.072:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(103)]
>   Failed to launch GPU process.
>   [4576:5056:0725/193214.088:VERBOSE1:default_component_installer.cc(211)]
>   StartRegistration for Adobe Flash Player
>   [4576:5056:0725/193214.091:VERBOSE1:default_component_installer.cc(211)]
>   StartRegistration for Widevine Content Decryption Module
>   [4576:5056:0725/193214.092:VERBOSE1:default_component_installer.cc(200)]
>   Preinstalled component found for Widevine Content Decryption Module at
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\60.0.3112.72\WidevineCdm with version
>   1.4.8.1000. [4576:2324:0725/193214.092:VERBOSE1:crl_set_fetcher.cc(104)] Loaded
>   211542 bytes of CRL set from disk
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.092:VERBOSE1:crl_set_fetcher.cc(125)] Installed
>   CRL set #3872
>   [4576:5056:0725/193214.092:VERBOSE1:default_component_installer.cc(211)]
>   StartRegistration for Subresource Filter Rules
>   [4576:5056:0725/193214.093:VERBOSE1:default_component_installer.cc(211)]
>   StartRegistration for EV Certs CT whitelist
>   [4576:5056:0725/193214.094:VERBOSE1:default_component_installer.cc(211)]
>   StartRegistration for Signed Tree Heads
>   [4576:5056:0725/193214.096:VERBOSE1:default_component_installer.cc(211)]
>   StartRegistration for Origin Trials
>   [4576:5056:0725/193214.097:VERBOSE1:default_component_installer.cc(211)]
>   StartRegistration for File Type Policies
>   [4576:5056:0725/193214.108:VERBOSE1:default_component_installer.cc(211)]
>   StartRegistration for SSL Error Assistant
>   [4576:5056:0725/193214.109:VERBOSE1:default_component_installer.cc(211)]
>   StartRegistration for Software Reporter Tool
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.123:INFO:easy_unlock_service_regular.cc(446)]
>   Initializing EasyUnlockService inside the user session.
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.132:VERBOSE1:component_updater_service.cc(92)]
>   CrxUpdateService starting up. First update attempt will take place in
>   360 seconds. Next update attempt will take place in 18000 seconds. 
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.132:VERBOSE1:default_component_installer.cc(346)]
>   FinishRegistration for Adobe Flash Player
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.132:VERBOSE1:default_component_installer.cc(383)]
>   Component ready, version 26.0.0.137 in
>   C:\Users\Sammy\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
>   Data\PepperFlash\26.0.0.137
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.132:VERBOSE1:default_component_installer.cc(346)]
>   FinishRegistration for Widevine Content Decryption Module
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.132:VERBOSE1:default_component_installer.cc(383)]
>   Component ready, version 1.4.8.1000 in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\60.0.3112.72\WidevineCdm
>   [4576:5708:0725/193214.132:VERBOSE1:widevine_cdm_component_installer.cc(387)]
>   UpdateCdmAdapter: version1.4.8.1000
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.132:VERBOSE1:default_component_installer.cc(346)]
>   FinishRegistration for Subresource Filter Rules
>   [4576:5708:0725/193214.132:VERBOSE1:widevine_cdm_component_installer.cc(388)]
>   - adapter_install_path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\60.0.3112.72\WidevineCdm_platform_specific\win_x64\widevinecdmadapter.dll
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.132:VERBOSE1:default_component_installer.cc(383)]
>   Component ready, version 7.54 in
>   C:\Users\Sammy\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Subresource
>   Filter\Unindexed Rules\7.54
>   [4576:5708:0725/193214.132:VERBOSE1:widevine_cdm_component_installer.cc(389)]
>   - adapter_version_path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\60.0.3112.72\WidevineCdm_platform_specific\win_x64\CdmAdapterVersion
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.132:VERBOSE1:default_component_installer.cc(346)]
>   FinishRegistration for EV Certs CT whitelist
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.132:VERBOSE1:default_component_installer.cc(383)]
>   Component ready, version 7 in
>   C:\Users\Sammy\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\EVWhitelist\7
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.132:VERBOSE1:ev_whitelist_component_installer.cc(107)]
>   Component ready, version 7 in
>   C:\Users\Sammy\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\EVWhitelist\7
>   [4576:5708:0725/193214.132:VERBOSE1:ev_whitelist_component_installer.cc(44)]
>   Reading EV whitelist from file:
>   C:\Users\Sammy\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
>   Data\EVWhitelist\7_platform_specific\all\ev_hashes_whitelist.bin
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.132:VERBOSE1:default_component_installer.cc(346)]
>   FinishRegistration for Signed Tree Heads
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.132:VERBOSE1:default_component_installer.cc(383)]
>   Component ready, version 458 in
>   C:\Users\Sammy\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
>   Data\CertificateTransparency\458
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.132:VERBOSE1:default_component_installer.cc(346)]
>   FinishRegistration for Origin Trials
>   [4576:5708:0725/193214.133:VERBOSE1:packed_ct_ev_whitelist.cc(66)]
>   Uncompressing EV whitelist of size 674082
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.135:VERBOSE1:default_component_installer.cc(346)]
>   FinishRegistration for File Type Policies
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.135:VERBOSE1:default_component_installer.cc(383)]
>   Component ready, version 11 in
>   C:\Users\Sammy\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
>   Data\FileTypePolicies\11
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.135:VERBOSE1:file_type_policies_component_installer.cc(85)]
>   Component ready, version 11 in
>   C:\Users\Sammy\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
>   Data\FileTypePolicies\11
>   [4576:5056:0725/193214.135:VERBOSE1:file_type_policies_component_installer.cc(42)]
>   Reading Download File Types from file:
>   C:\Users\Sammy\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
>   Data\FileTypePolicies\11\download_file_types.pb
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.135:VERBOSE1:default_component_installer.cc(346)]
>   FinishRegistration for SSL Error Assistant
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.135:VERBOSE1:default_component_installer.cc(383)]
>   Component ready, version 3 in
>   C:\Users\Sammy\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
>   Data\SSLErrorAssistant\3
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.135:VERBOSE1:default_component_installer.cc(346)]
>   FinishRegistration for Software Reporter Tool
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.135:VERBOSE1:default_component_installer.cc(383)]
>   Component ready, version 20.114.2 in
>   C:\Users\Sammy\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
>   Data\SwReporter\20.114.2
>   [4576:5528:0725/193214.136:VERBOSE1:widevine_cdm_component_installer.cc(226)]
>   Register Widevine CDM with Chrome
>   [4576:5708:0725/193214.139:VERBOSE1:ev_whitelist_component_installer.cc(60)]
>   EV whitelist: Successfully loaded.
>   [4576:4552:0725/193214.139:VERBOSE1:packed_ct_ev_whitelist.cc(26)]
>   Setting new EV Certs whitelist.
>   [4576:4552:0725/193215.059:VERBOSE1:proxy_service.cc(1248)] Failed
>   configuring with PAC script, falling-back to manual proxy servers.
>   [4576:4552:0725/193215.103:VERBOSE1:proxy_service.cc(1248)] Failed
>   configuring with PAC script, falling-back to manual proxy servers.
>   [9364:7336:0725/193259.182:VERBOSE1:statistics_recorder.cc(542)]
>   Collections of all histograms Histogram:
>   Mojo.System.GetParentPlatformHandleSyncTime recorded 1 samples, mean =
>   0.0 (flags = 0x1) 0  ------------------------------------------------------------------------O (1 = 100.0%) 1  ...
>
> Histogram: Mojo.System.MessagesAcceptedPerEvent recorded 6 samples,
>   mean = 4.7 (flags = 0x1) 0  ...  4 
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------O (5 = 83.3%) {0.0%} 5  ...  8  --------------O
>   (1 = 16.7%) {83.3%} 9  ...
>
> Histogram: Mojo.System.Node.ConnectedPeers recorded 1 samples, mean =
>   0.0 (flags = 0x1) 0  ------------------------------------------------------------------------O (1 = 100.0%) 1  ...
>
> Histogram: Mojo.System.Node.PendingChildren recorded 1 samples, mean =
>   0.0 (flags = 0x1) 0  ------------------------------------------------------------------------O (1 = 100.0%) 1  ...
>
> Histogram:
>   TaskScheduler.DetachDuration.ContentChildBackgroundBlockingPool
>   recorded 0 samples (flags = 0x1) 0 ...
>
> Histogram: TaskScheduler.DetachDuration.ContentChildBackgroundPool
>   recorded 0 samples (flags = 0x1) 0 ...
>
> Histogram:
>   TaskScheduler.DetachDuration.ContentChildForegroundBlockingPool
>   recorded 0 samples (flags = 0x1) 0 ...
>
> Histogram: TaskScheduler.DetachDuration.ContentChildForegroundPool
>   recorded 0 samples (flags = 0x1) 0 ...
>
> Histogram:
>   TaskScheduler.NumTasksBeforeDetach.ContentChildBackgroundBlockingPool
>   recorded 0 samples (flags = 0x1) 0 ...
>
> Histogram:
>   TaskScheduler.NumTasksBeforeDetach.ContentChildBackgroundPool recorded
>   0 samples (flags = 0x1) 0 ...
>
> Histogram:
>   TaskScheduler.NumTasksBeforeDetach.ContentChildForegroundBlockingPool
>   recorded 0 samples (flags = 0x1) 0 ...
>
> Histogram:
>   TaskScheduler.NumTasksBeforeDetach.ContentChildForegroundPool recorded
>   0 samples (flags = 0x1) 0 ...
>
> Histogram:
>   TaskScheduler.NumTasksBetweenWaits.ContentChildBackgroundBlockingPool
>   recorded 0 samples (flags = 0x1) 0 ...
>
> Histogram:
>   TaskScheduler.NumTasksBetweenWaits.ContentChildBackgroundPool recorded
>   0 samples (flags = 0x1) 0 ...
>
> Histogram:
>   TaskScheduler.NumTasksBetweenWaits.ContentChildForegroundBlockingPool
>   recorded 0 samples (flags = 0x1) 0 ...
>
> Histogram:
>   TaskScheduler.NumTasksBetweenWaits.ContentChildForegroundPool recorded
>   0 samples (flags = 0x1) 0 ...
>
> Histogram:
>   TaskScheduler.TaskLatencyMicroseconds.BackgroundTaskPriority recorded
>   0 samples (flags = 0x1) 0 ...
>
> Histogram:
>   TaskScheduler.TaskLatencyMicroseconds.BackgroundTaskPriority.MayBlock
>   recorded 0 samples (flags = 0x1) 0 ...
>
> Histogram:
>   TaskScheduler.TaskLatencyMicroseconds.UserBlockingTaskPriority
>   recorded 0 samples (flags = 0x1) 0 ...
>
> Histogram:
>   TaskScheduler.TaskLatencyMicroseconds.UserBlockingTaskPriority.MayBlock
>   recorded 0 samples (flags = 0x1) 0 ...
>
> Histogram:
>   TaskScheduler.TaskLatencyMicroseconds.UserVisibleTaskPriority recorded
>   0 samples (flags = 0x1) 0 ...
>
> Histogram:
>   TaskScheduler.TaskLatencyMicroseconds.UserVisibleTaskPriority.MayBlock
>   recorded 0 samples (flags = 0x1) 0 ...
>
> Histogram: TrackedObjects.GetRetiredOrCreateThreadData recorded 3
>   samples, mean = 0.0 (flags = 0x1) 0 
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------O (3 = 100.0%) 1  ...
>
> Histogram: UMA.Histograms.Activity.utility recorded 70 samples, mean =
>   3.9 (flags = 0x1) 0  ---O                                                                      (1 = 1.4%) 1 
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------O (23 = 32.9%) {1.4%} 2  O
>   (0 = 0.0%) {34.3%} 3 
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------O (23 = 32.9%) {34.3%} 4  ...  8 
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------O (23 = 32.9%) {67.1%} 9  ...
>
> Histogram: V8.Initializer.LoadV8Snapshot.Result recorded 1 samples,
>   mean = 0.0 (flags = 0x1) 0 
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------O (1 = 100.0%) 1  ...
>
> Histogram: V8.Initializer.OpenV8File.Result recorded 2 samples, mean =
>   0.0 (flags = 0x1) 0  ------------------------------------------------------------------------O (2 = 100.0%) 1  ...

I really can't find how to solve this, even after uninstalling completely Chrome. I guess it might be a conflict with another program (I'm using Avast as antivirus and TuneUp too), but I can find it.

I have a Windows 10 Professionnal Edition, Intel i5 6500, AMD RX480 8GB (normal one without overclocking), 16 GB DDR4 of Ram. Everything work perfectly except for chrome

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This probably belongs at [su] instead of SO.

Comment: Ah ? I found similar question on SO, so I was thinking I should post here. I'll post in Super User then if it's not the right place. Thanks for the info